# using regular expression for searching multiple key words from cells

Tags: python, regex, text-mining, data-analysis, orange

I have to write a code for searching regular expression from an excel sheet which has sentences grouped together. I have managed to find the key words representing each sentence. When i run the below mention code it finds only one key word from one cell and moves to next cell. I have tried to display the requirement in the table

[image]

```
\bphrase\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,6}?one\b|\bphrase\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,6}?two\b|\bphrase\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,6}?three\b|\bphrase\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,6}?four\b|
```

Comment: Can you include your code? That’s just a regular expression. Your data should not be shared as a picture, please replace it with the text itself.

Comment: I am using a function of orange 3(Text mining).  Hence i require only the regular expression and not the entire code. Sorry but stackoverflow was not allowing me to add table hence i added the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The regex:

```
\b(phrase)\b\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,6}?\b(one|two|three|four)\b
```

1. `\b(phrase)\b` matches `phrase` on a word boundary.
2. `W+`: matches one or more non-word characters (typically spaces).
3. `(?:\w+\W+){0,6}?` Matches between 0 and 6 times, as few times as possible, one or more word characters followed by one or more non-word characters.
4. `\b(one|two|three|four)\b` Matches `one`, `two`, `three` or `four` on a word boundary.

The code:

```
import re

text = "This sentence has phrase one and phrase word word two and phrase word three and phrase four phrase too many words too many words too many words four again."

l = [m[1] + ' ' + m[2] for m in re.finditer(r'\b(phrase)\b\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,6}?\b(one|two|three|four)\b', text)]
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['phrase one', 'phrase two', 'phrase three', 'phrase four']
```

Comment: thanks Ronald for your comment. My appologies that i forgot to mention that i require the regex code to insert in Orange3 text mining module.